# GLM, Poisson - números de contagem não inteiros (média)

Tags: r

Eu estou fazendo *GLM* para dados de frequência de um comportamento x. Como eu tenho dia 1 e dia 2 de observações, fiz a média das frequências desse dois dias, logo, os meus dados de contagem não são números inteiros. No entanto, não estou conseguindo fazer os modelos quando utilizo a distribuição de *Poisson*.

Como resolvo isso?

Estou ajustando modelo da seguinte forma:

```
al1<-glm(cbind(al)~sp*sexo,poisson(link="log"),data=abfm)
```

Mas recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
Warning messages: 
1: In dpois(y, mu, log = TRUE) : non-integer x = 4.500000 
2: In dpois(y, mu, log = TRUE) : non-integer x = 7.500000
```

Comment: Você precisa detalhar mais a sua pergunta. Não está conseguindo por que? Recebe um erro? Sua dúvida é mesmo de programação, em relação ao código da análise (ou seu resultado), ou estatística?

Comment: Olá Erlon, obrigada pelo interesse. Meus dados de contagem não são números inteiros porque trata-se de médias. Então quando faço GLM com distribuição de Poisson, link=log, dá erro. Por exemplo:           al1<-glm(cbind(al)~sp*sexo,poisson(link="log"),data=abfm)
Warning messages:
1: In dpois(y, mu, log = TRUE) : non-integer x = 4.500000
2: In dpois(y, mu, log = TRUE) : non-integer x = 7.500000

Comment: Bruna, edite esses detalhes na própria pergunta, tentando deixar mais claro o seu problema, conforme o @Molx sugeriu!

Comment: tentei editar a pergunta, mas ela foi rejeitada. para mim, é uma pena essa pergunta ser excluida...

Comment: Ela foi excluída? Eu não excluí....

Comment: @DanielFalbel a pergunta não vai ser excluída, ela só está pendente para que as edições ocorram antes de aparecerem novas respostas (do contrário poderia acontecer igual aquela outra pergunta que você respondeu mas o cara estava perguntando outra coisa!). Tente editar novamente, se não der certo, qualquer coisa me passe os detalhes da edição que eu edito e a gente vota para reabrir a pergunta!

Comment: @CarlosCinelli agora aceitaram a edição. Vamos tentar reabrir?

Comment: @DanielFalbel valeu, votei para reabrir, já tem 3 votos

Answer (score 2):

Não tem como usar a média das duas observações e ao mesmo tempo usar a distribuição de Poisson. Você pdoeria tentar descobrir qual é a distribuição de probabilidade da média de duas variáveis aleatórias Poisson i.i.d, mas acho que essa não é a melhor saída.

Para mim, a melhor saída seria usar um modelo de medidas repetidas, e considerar um efeito aleatório de indivíduo para cada dia.

Para isso, considerando que você tem um banco de dados da seguinte forma:

```
> dados <- data.frame(
+   id = 1:100,
+   explicativa = runif(100, 0, 20)
+   )
> 
> dados$r1 <- rpois(100, dados$explicativa)
> dados$r2 <- rpois(100, dados$explicativa)
> 
> head(dados)
  id explicativa r1 r2
1  1    9.082513 16 14
2  2   17.741123 14 29
3  3   10.819865 13 12
4  4   18.527938 22 25
5  5    4.828392  6  7
6  6   13.986794 14 15
```

`r1` e `r2` são as frequências observadas no dia 1 e no dia 2.

Transforme seus dados no formato `tidy/long`:

```
library(tidyr);library(dplyr)
dados <- dados %>% gather(dia, resposta, starts_with("r"))
```

Depois ajustaria um modelo da seguinte forma:

```
library(lme4)    
modelo <- glmer(resposta ~ explicativa + (0 + dia | id), data = dados, family = poisson)
```

Assim, você estará considerando que para cada indivíduo existe uma variação aleatória relacionada ao dia em que ele está sendo medido.

Comment: Obrigada, Daniel. Me ajudou bastante!

Comment: Daniel, o pacote que você me indicou não está disponível. pacote dplyr e o argumento para tidyr está dando errado. Continuarei tentando....

Comment: você instalou os dois pacotes? `install.packages("dplyr")` e `install.packages("tidyr")`. em seguida use `library(tidyr);library(dplyr)`